# Python. I want to restrict the inputs of my guessing game to integers in an interactive way

Tags: python, performance, pygame

Newbie here. I'm using the variable `number_guessed` to store the guessed number and the correct number is 9. I want whoever's playing the game to only enter integers and I understand the variable stores string. Line 3 creates an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'`. I understand why this is and would appreciate some help with an interactive way to go about this problem. By the way, I'm using Python 3 and here's my code.

```
number_guessed = input('Guess a number between 0 and 10?  ')
guess_count = 1
if type(int(number_guessed)) != int:   # restricting input to integers: start
    print('Whole numbers only!')
    number_guessed = input('Guess a number between 0 and 10?  ')   # restricting input to integers: end
if int(number_guessed) == 9:
    print("Correct. That's some good luck right there:)")
while int(number_guessed) != 9:
    number_guessed = input('Try Again! Guess a number between 0 and 10?  ')
    if type(int(number_guessed)) != int:  # restricting input to integers: start
        print('Whole numbers only!')
        number_guessed = input('Guess a number between 0 and 10?  ')  # restricting input to integers: end
    guess_count += 1
    if int(number_guessed) == 9:
        print("Correct. That's some good luck right there:)")
        exit()
    if guess_count == 3:
        msg = f"""
You're out of Luck!
It was 9 by the way
"""
        print(msg)
```

Please save my soul. Would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `int()` will try to convert whatever is passed to it to an integer, which fails when it isn't a value that can be converted to an integer, resulting in the ValueError exception being thrown.

A solution is to 'catch' that exception like this:

```
number_guessed = input('Guess a number between 0 and 10?  ')
try:
    # try to convert it to an actual integer instead of a string
    number_guessed = int(number_guessed)
except ValueError:
    print('Whole numbers only!')
```

What doesn't work is to try and check the type of what was entered, that will always be a string, since you enter the number as text (that's the problem you're trying to solve), so some of the suggested solutions checking the type of the input won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `int` on a string. To fix this problem, you can do:

```
if type(number_guessed) is int:
    print('Whole numbers only!')
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work. If a string is passed, it should use the strings length as a guess. In general, it’s more convenient to use the `isinstance` method, which is a built in function. Hope this is helpful :)

```py
the_num = 9
guess = 0
guess_count = 0
while guess != the_num:
    if guess_count >= 3:
        print(“oh no!”)
        break
    guess = input(“guess a number in [0,10]   “)
    if isinstance(guess, int):
        if guess == the_num:
            print(“yay!”)
            break
        if guess != the_num:
            guess_count += 1
    elif isinstance(guess, str):
        if len(guess) == the_num:
            print(“yay”)
            break
        if len(guess) != the_num:
            guess_count += 1
    else:
        guess_count += 1
```

My apology also for making edit, I’m not very efficient with the iOS app ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

your logic is correct but you are casting your input to ing before the comparisson.
`if type(int(number_guessed)) != int:`

instead, you should try casting your raw input to `int` before comparing the number. You can do it by replacing the above line with

```
try:
    number_guessed = int(number_guessed)
except:
   pass
if type(number_guessed) != int: 
   ...
```

this code will first try to convert your input to an int in the `try` block. If it is successful, your variable will be treated as an int later in the code thus redirecting the user to the `if` clause. 
If the cast fails, then the code inside the `except` block will run. The `pass` keyword in the except clause tells your application to ignore what happened in the `try` clause thus your `number_guessed` will remain a `string`, redirecting the user to the `else` clause.

> Another note - try to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) your code up a bit. you are repeating
>   the same logic in two places - initial guess (lines 3-7) and
>   subsequent guesses (lines 10-14). try to restructure your code to
>   extract the key functionalities into separate functions.

Working code:

```
number_guessed = input('Guess a number between 0 and 10?  ')
guess_count = 1
try:
    number_guessed = int(number_guessed)
except:
   pass
if type(number_guessed) != int:   # restricting input to integers: start
    print('Whole numbers only!')
    number_guessed = input('Guess a number between 0 and 10?  ')   # restricting input to integers: end
if int(number_guessed) == 9:
    print("Correct. That's some good luck right there:)")
while int(number_guessed) != 9:
    number_guessed = input('Try Again! Guess a number between 0 and 10?  ')
    try:
        number_guessed = int(number_guessed)
    except:
        pass
    if type(number_guessed) != int:  # restricting input to integers: start
        print('Whole numbers only!')
        number_guessed = input('Guess a number between 0 and 10?  ')  # restricting input to integers: end
    guess_count += 1
    if int(number_guessed) == 9:
        print("Correct. That's some good luck right there:)")
        exit()
    if guess_count == 3:
        msg = f"""
You're out of Luck!
It was 9 by the way
"""
        print(msg)
```